# convert perl function to php function (unpack, pack)

Tags: php, perl, binary, decimal, data-conversion

I want to convert the binary representation of a number to a number in PHP. I'm currently using the following in Perl:

```
sub binary2decimal {
    return unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . shift, -32)));
}
```

For example, `binary2decimal('1101')` returns `13`, and `binary2decimal('1110')` returns `14`.

Comment: By the way, `sub binary2decimal { oct("0b" . shift) }` is a simpler implementation in Perl.

Comment: what is the shift? i dont know perl...

Comment: In a sub, it's short for `shift(@_)`. `@_` contains the sub's arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need this function: http://php.net/bindec

But i think this implementation also does the same:

```
function binary2decimal($param) {
  return unpack("N", pack("B32",substr(str_repeat("0",32) . $param, -32)));
}
```

Comment: No it`s not this function, look at mine. there is pack into unpack...

Comment: it does the same. but i added a more literal transscript also

Comment: Why don't you try the bindec function? It does the same. It converts from binary to decimal.